# How to change parent view classname on child view load?

Tags: ember.js

I need to change the parent view classname on child view load the code would be like

```
  var ChildView = Em.View.extend({


       willInsertElement            :   function() {

          this.get('parentView').set('classnames',['ChildView']);

        },
        template             :   Em.Handlebars.compile(template)

      });
```

Regards
Chandru.

Answer (score 0):

Use [classNameBindings](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#property_classNameBindings) and send the event from the child view to update the property.

Consider this example:

```
{{#view App.AParentView}}
  {{view App.AChildView}}
{{/view}}
```

The app:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.AParentView = Em.View.extend({
  bgColor: 'lightgray',
  classNames: ['parent-view'],
  classNameBindings: 'bgColor',

  updateBg: function(bg) {
   this.set('bgColor', bg);
  }
});

App.AChildView = Em.View.extend({
  classNames: ['child-view', 'blue'],
  willInsertElement: function() {
    this.get('parentView').send('updateBg', 'green');
  }
});
```

The CSS to see it actually working:

```
html, body {
    margin: 20px;
}

.parent-view {
  padding: 4rem;
}

.child-view {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.lightgray {
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

See the jsbin [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sopecoba/2).